# How do i get only the phone number and not the country code or how can i extracct the phone number from this response?

Tags: flutter

I am using the following library to extract the phone number of the user: I want to enable auto filling of mobile number,
I am using the PhoneFieldHint library and am able to get the phone number with the country code, but I want to get only the phone number.
Question: How do I get only the phone number and not the country code, or how can I extract the phone number from this response?